# Generating Indivdiual Dot Plot in R with Multipe Factors

Tags: r, graphics, graph, plot, ggplot2

I'm trying to generate an individual dot plot with multiple factors in R that's similar to the one produced by minitab.

I've been able to produce the individual dot plot in R but I can't figure out how to add grouping to the x-axis. For example I have a Color and a Type that I'd like to display on the x-axis, each Type has two colors and I'd like this put on the same graph but can't figure it out for a dot plot.

The result should look similar to this grouping but a dot plot instead and only have 1 graph, I'm just trying to illustrate the grouping.

http://ajpendo.physiology.org/content/280/5/E804/F6.small.gif

sorry can't post the image, too much of a noob to stack :)

I've scoured the web but can't find much help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a number of ways in R.

The first is to use the `lattice` package:

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(lat ~ long | cut(depth, 3),
        data = quakes, 
        aspect = "iso", 
        pch = ".", 
        cex = 2, 
        type = c("p", "g"), 
        xlab = "Longitude", 
        ylab = "Latitude", 
        strip = strip.custom(strip.names = TRUE, var.name = "Depth"))
```

[image]

And the second is in ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- quakes
df$cut_depth <- cut(quakes$depth, 3)
ggplot(quakes, aes(x=long, y=lat)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(.~cut_depth)
```

[image]

Comment: this is similar to what i'm going for.  i commented below; the boss wants the strip titles on the bottom and AFAIK ggplot won't let you do this.  i tried plotting each categorical factor as it's own plot then using grid.layout to arrange the plots for the same effect but it's not working out.  theres too many format changes when I do this. looks like i'll have to try and convince him to accept it the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ggplot to do this most directly. Let's say you have a data.frame with the following columns:

dta := x, y, color, condition

where x,y are numeric and color, condition are factors. Then you can do the following:

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(dta, aes(x = x, y = y, color = color)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ condition)
```

alternatively, in regular R you could do:

```
plot(dta$x, dta$y, col = dta$color, pch = dta$condition)
```

however, this might be way too busy.

jim

Comment: the ggplot method works but the boss want's the facet label at the bottom.  after searching it looks like there's no functionality for that in R.